# Finding the limit() of a symbolic function operating on a matrix

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have the following Matlab 2014a snippet:

```
syms x
A=[0.8 0.6; -0.6 0.8]
f(x) = eig((0.9*A)^x)
limit(f(x), x, inf)
```

where `A` is a 2-by-2 matrix and `x` is a symbolic variable. The call to `eig` in this case will return two complex numbers. I'm trying to have Matlab tell me the limit of this function as `x` goes to infinity.

Unfortunately I cannot get past the following error:

```
Error using mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: An arithmetical expression is expected. [ln]
```

If I manually plot the return values, I can visually see the limit, but there must be a way to use `limit`. Initially, I thought this may be a problem with `eig` returning two values, so I tried putting the results into another vector, slicing off a row, and then pasing that on to `limit` ... same problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since `eig(A^b)=eig(A).^b`, (for integer `b`) does this work: `limit(eig(0.9*A).^x,x,Inf)`?

Comment: Interesting.  That does give me the limit I expect, but I think we've lost the complex part of the returned value from eig().

Comment: Do you have any examples where the limit is not just 0 or Inf?

Comment: That's a good question; I'm pretty new to this stuff so I'll have to think about it a little more.  I'm not sure I fully understand the consequence of losing the imaginary part.  To me it seems like you can't do that as these points should capable of being plotted on a 2-D Re/Im plane.

Comment: Please edit your question to show all of your code, including how you take the limit, to make your question/issue repeatable by others. Make sure you include the allocation/definition of all values and symbolic variable so that it's runnable. Include any error message you receive in full. Also, what `version` of Matlab are you using?

Comment: Also, you might show how you "manually plot the return values" too. What you use actual values for `x`, is it a purely numeric calculation or are you doing that in symbolic math as well?